# 59 minute video, 85000 frames: render speed: 30 frames per minute, Estimated time: 48 hours. Are my settings correct?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Frame Rate: 24fps

Rendering in HDTV 720p

Resolution: 1920px X 1200px

Turned off: Anti Aliasing, Sampled Motion Blur, Disabled all Metadata

Output: H.264 RGB, disabled Lossless output

Audio Codec: Mp3 320kbps

Are these correct settings to render 85000 frames? According to the current render rate, estimated is 48 hours. **IS THIS HOW IT SHOULD BE?**

Answer (score 5):

Short answer,

## Yes

In order to render 85000 frames at a rate of 30 per **minute**, then you will end up with almost exactly 48 hours. This is simple math, as you have a rate of execution (30 f/m) and a quantity (8.5 10^4).

**EDIT** as per further information.
No, these are not the right settings. Specifically the render dimensions.
You mention a non standard aspect ratio (1920x1200, standard HD is 1920x1080) and then you mention 720p. If you research 720p, it is in the 16:9 aspect ratio, and 720 pixels high. The resulting resolution is 1280×720. I would also recommend rendering to stills and then compiling into a video later, as if your render stops at any time, even at frame 84999, then the entire file is useless and you have wasted 2 days of rendering.

Comment: I am actually asking if those are correct settings or not, to render 85000 frames in good quality or am I missing something there? I did the math and therefore estimated it myself to 48 hours.

Comment: @satyam_m I have updated it

Comment: @satyam_m please edit your question and make clear what you are after. Before committing 2 days of your life to a project makes some test and see if the quality is indeed what you need.Turning off anti-alias might result in  jagged edges, no motion blur might look strange. For long projects like this is quite unsafe to render a s a video file. Do render as an image sequence and encode later.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds about right. Unless I'm missing something aswell...

59 min x 30 frames = 1770 (aprox 1770 frames per hour). 85000 frames / 1770 = aprox 48.

Comment: Just a note, I only answered to help this guy out. This question is most likely going to get closed as too localized.

Comment: I am actually asking if those are correct settings or not, to render 85000 frames in good quality or am I missing something there? I did the math and therefore estimated it myself to 48 hours.